# It can't load css js file when I change theme in magento2

Tags: magento2, custom-theme

[image]

There are my theme's file struct

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to run below commands in magento2 directory

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade //Install/upgrade modules, clear caches, di, view_preprocessed, etc.
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy [<languages>] // Generate static content
```